Newly set ssd GPT partition menu is greyed out in Windows 11
I installed new ssd hikvision e100, and when i got to disk managment it ask me to initalize. I did it with GPT but now here is the below status. I am not able to assign volume to it. What i am doing wrong. its grey out.


It doesn’t appear to have a file system. It also doesn’t appear to be functioning. Have you tried rebooting your system?

There is no space for creating a new volume because there is already a single volume (Disk 0 partition 1) taking up all available space. That volume does not appear to be formatted with any specific filesystem yet. Format it and assign a drive letter to it (right click on the blue/white part, not the grey part) and you should be able to use it.
Also it should be noted that the disk appears to have been initialized with MBR, not GPT. It would say Convert to MBR Disk instead of Convert to GPT Disk if it were initialized as GPT. It's greyed out because the disk already has a volume(partition) and windows disk manager doesn't support changing partition schemes when the disk already has partitions.

There are four port in my board, i check in one by one and in third socket it worked. Remember, i have also changed the power supply cable port. So it worked.
